# Status Bar clock has been truncated on iPhoneX

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, clock, iphone-x

After adding a gradient layer to the statusbar and make it light or dark for different view controllers, at some random point in navigation, my clock in the status bar of notch iPhones has become truncated. like 1... or ...

I have tried these two solutions for make statusbar content white; But this has no effect on this random clock behaviour.

this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

or this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
}
```

Both of them changes my status bar color of content. Any idea about what is cause of this behavior???

[image: clock problem]

and this is how I make the status bar gradient:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func makeStatusBarGradient(){
        let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
        let gradientLayer1 = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer1.frame = statusBarView.frame
        gradientLayer1.colors = [UIColor.APColors.redGradient.cgColor, UIColor.APColors.orangeGradient.cgColor]
        gradientLayer1.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer1.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer1.cornerRadius = 0
        gradientLayer1.zPosition = -10
        gradientLayer1.name = "gradient"
        //Change status bar color
        if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView{
            statusBar.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer1)
        }
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
    func clearStatusBarGradient(){
        if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView{
            if let layers = statusBar.layer.sublayers?.filter({$0.name == "gradient"}){
                if (layers.count > 0){
                    layers.first?.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }
        }
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

and, the APColors are:

```
extension UIColor {
      struct APColors {
            static var redGradient : UIColor { return UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.42, blue: 0.24, alpha: 1) }
            static var orangeGradient : UIColor { return UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.19, blue: 0.42, alpha: 1)}

      }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share how do u apply gradient color to status vbar?

Comment: @EmreÖnder Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using extension on UILabel, which override it's `intrinsicContentSize`. (or maybe you swizzling this method) So status bar clock label trigger it and got wrong intrinsicContentSize. Try to fix textSize calculation in this overrided method, or avoid overriding it if possible.

I can guess you're using UILabel+Padding from popular SO answer, so check if you've got this:

```
if let insets = padding {
  insetsWidth += insets.left + insets.right
  insetsHeight += insets.top + insets.bottom
  textWidth -= insetsWidth
}
```

if you do, then simply change it:

```
if let insets = padding {
  insetsWidth += insets.left + insets.right
  insetsHeight += insets.top + insets.bottom
  textWidth -= insetsWidth
} else {
  return contentSize
}
```

Comment: I'm impressed of how you guessed my code. Excellent Answer. Thanks. @Unreal Developer

Answer (score 0):

As i do not know what's the APColor, so I changed the line with below & everything is working fine.

```
gradientLayer1.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.orange.cgColor]
```

1. Try to change the same line and check your issue is solved or not. Most probably, APColor does not caused the issue.
2. Check is their any multiple stuffs is in you **statusbar** is available or not. e.g. indicator etc.
3. If you added anything else in your status bar then let me know.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Actually it's also ok for me most of the time. But after a bit navigation in different pages, or make app minimized and restore again, or even make the phone locked and unlocked again, the problem appears suddenly. I couldn't find any pattern or sequence of navigation which causes this problem.

Comment: @AbbasSabeti Do you face the same issue by doing all things that mentioned above if you dont add the gradient?

Comment: The problem is not gradient. The same result has been achieved with statusbar background color.

Comment: @AbbasSabeti Then probably its device issue. Check same in other device if possible.

Comment: Exact same problem on iPhone XS Max, iPhone X, and every notched iOS Simulator.

Comment: @UnrealDeveloper You've just solved it, dude. Thanks again.